# Swift dynamically create editable modal from Stepper component?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swiftui, mobile

I have a Stepper component that corresponds to number of people (for now, I don't want to restrict what the stepper goes up to, but users will likely never enter more than 10). I want to dynamically generate a box that is essentially a Person object/class based on the current value of Stepper.

Current code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var numPeople = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Enter number of people below:")
            Stepper("\(numPeople.formatted()) People", value: $numPeople)
        }
    }
```

Desired outcome if user clicks plus button until the number 3.

[image]

Should this be done using a for loop (or ForEach loop)? Should a component other than Stepper be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways of doing this but for growth sake you can consider a `PersonModel` and basing the stepper on the `count` of `Array<PersonModel>` using a computed variable that adds and removes from the array.

```
import SwiftUI
struct PersonModel: Identifiable{
    let id: UUID = .init()
    let name: String
}
class PersonVM: ObservableObject{
    @Published var people: [PersonModel] = []
    
    var personCount: Int{
        get{
            //Single source of truth.
            people.count
        }
        set{
            let diff: Int = people.count - newValue
            
            if diff == 0{
                //No change
            } else if diff < 0 { //Add the difference
                let new: [PersonModel] = (0..<abs(diff)).map{ n in
                    PersonModel(name: "Person \(people.count + n + 1)")
                }
                people.append(contentsOf: new)
            } else if !people.isEmpty{ //Remove the difference if the array isn't empty
                people.removeLast(diff)
            }
        }

    }
}

@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct PersonView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm: PersonVM = .init()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Enter number of people below:")
            Stepper("\(vm.people.count.formatted()) People", value: $vm.personCount, in: 0...10, step: 1)
            ForEach(vm.people) { person in
                ZStack{
                    Color.blue
                    Text(person.name)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }.padding(2)
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked great! op